# Is it possible to read http/2 request header fields in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-headers, http2

Just curious, I can see some http2 pseudo headers fields like `:method`,
`:scheme`,`:authority` when I go to some website that has enabled http2.

Example, for homepage of `www.ft.com`, there are these pseudo request headers:

`:authority:www.ft.com
:method:GET
:path:/
:scheme:https`

Is it possible to read/modify those fields in chrome extension, just like we can read/modify `Cookie`, `Referer`, `User-Agent`?

Or if it is not possible in chrome, can we do it in other browsers like firefox?

Comment: Please provide the URL of a website where you see such pseudo headers.

Comment: So you want a proxy-like extension?

Comment: @Makyen, as an example, please checkout Financial Times: http://www.ft.com, the homepage's request header has this: ```:authority:www.ft.com
:method:GET
:path:/
:scheme:https```

Comment: @laike9m, yes. I want to read the request header fields of http2 before the request is sent. My first approach is using `chrome.webRequest` in chrome extension(https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), but it has not supported for http2 as far as I know

Comment: I searched for the same thing not long ago, so I think it's pretty hard, as least for now. There's an internal page in Chrome in which you can see every incoming HTTP/2 frame(chrome://net-internals/#export), but you can't access those data from an extension.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm doing it with the declarativeNetRequest api but I get an error when i try to modify headers with a colon in front (HTTP/2 headers)

Answer (score -1):

So all HTTP/2 headers start with a : (to distinguish them from HTTP/1.x headers)

Not aware of any extensions to alter them, but I guess the real question is why would you want to?

Comment: i'm thinking about the possibilities to modify a HTTP/2 request header. There are situations that you want to block or redirect certain http request.